# Fargate aws-rails-provisioner ignoring --profile option

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-fargate, aws-rails-provisioner

I created an aws-rails-provisioner project following the guidelines on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-rails-provisioner) and copied their default yaml file for a single application.  When I ran

`aws-rails-provisioner build --profile FargateSandboxAdmin --with-cicd -f ./aws-rails-provisioner.yml`

it appeared to accept the profile parameter with no issues, however when I went to deploy it using

`aws-rails-provisioner deploy --profile FargateSandboxAdmin`

I received an error that --profile was not valid:

`/Users/todd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/aws-rails-provisioner-0.0.1.rc2/bin/aws-rails-provisioner:128:in '<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method 'profile' for main:Object (NameError)
    from /Users/todd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/bin/aws-rails-provisioner:23:in 'load'
    from /Users/todd/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/bin/aws-rails-provisioner:23:in '<main>'`

The same is true when using the `-p` flag instead of `--profile`. After running a "regular" deploy with `aws-rails-provisioner deploy` it created all the objects under my parent account and not the sandbox I set up for it.

Is there any way to use profiles with aws-rails-provisioner or is it not supported at this time?